# Referring URL Redirect after login

Tags: php

I have the below PHP code:

```
<?php

// let's add a ref url feature for quick guidance.

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?ref=$ref";

header("Location: $actual_link");

if (empty($ref)) {
    # do nothing...
} else {
    $redirect_to_ref = header("Location: $ref");
    header("Location: test.php");
}

}

?>
<?php

function checkRef() {
    if (isset($redirect_to_ref)) {
        $redirect_to_ref;
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    if(file_exists('users/' . $username . '.xml')){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('users/' . $username . '.xml', 0, true);
        if($password == $xml->password){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            checkRef();
            die;
        }
    }
    $error = true;
}
 ?>
```

This code is for a simple xml login script. This will just log the person in, and if the person came from a page that required one to be logged in, but one wasn't, I would like it to add the referrer in the url bar, and upon login success, redirect the user to that referred url. However, this is now giving me an error 500. Please help...

Comment: Use `header("Location: $ref");`? Do you test if login is successful?

Comment: Are they redirected anywhere currently?

Comment: Currently, they will be redirected, after successful login, to the referring url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
//GLOBAL FUNCTION TO GET THE CURRENT URL:
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}

// USE SESSION TO SET A VARIABLE FOR THE REF. URL:
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['ref_url'])){
    header("Location: " . $_SESSION['ref_url']);
    unset($_SESSION['ref_url']);
}



//IN ALL OTHER PAGES; SET THE URL OF THE CURRENT PAGE TO THE $_SESSION['ref_url'] VARIABLE LIKE SO
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['ref_url'] = curPageURL();
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to redirect users to the referring url after they login
>   successfully

Assuming the user already logged in successfully, you can check if 
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is set and redirect accordingly, i.e.:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?ref=$ref";

if(isset($ref)){
    header("Location: $ref");
}else{
   //this doesn't make sense since the redirection will be made to the same page and $ref is empty. 
   //Think about something else when HTTP_REFERER isn't set. 
   //header("Location: $actual_link");
}
```

Comment: How would I check if a variable exits or not? if...else...elseif... statements